# Character encoding Russian , Turkish

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding, meta-tags

I got Russian character problem. I used utf8 ,windows-1251 but  it seems like ?????? (русский). how can i solve this problem ?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li><a href="#">Türkçe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">русский</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

when i tried to write russian char into notepad++ it shows like ????? too. where is the problem ?

Comment: it does not solve my problem. thanks

Comment: It will very probably solve your problem if you follow the advice properly. What encoding is the file you're in (look in your IDE) and what is the document's character set?

Comment: my IDE SHOWS IT. (RAPID PHP) BUT I WAS USING NOTEPAD++ FOR PHP AND HMTL. IF I CONVERT FILES TO ENCODING UTF8  IN NOTEPAD++ , DOES IT WORK?

Comment: You need to make sure your source file is the same encoding as the web page, and also that the characters are in the same encoding. If you copy&paste it from your question above, the characters are guaranteed to be UTF-8, that may be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the font installed on your system doesn't have cyrillic symbols? Because on my system, your example is displayed correctly.

Comment: what do you mean ?  when use turkish char , i can not use utf8, it is not show special Char Ç,Ö... when i put meta iso-8859-9 , it shows. Russian char never shows , it shows like ????? in utf8.

Comment: I mean, that depending on your system, maybe the font, your are using in your editor, doesn't have cyrillic symbols at all. So it soesn't matter, what code page you are using, you will always see ???.